# How to find the source codes of a program & control the soft from another pc

Tags: architecture

I want to find the source code of software buttons, in order to emulate it and execute those buttons switch (software) from another PC connected to it.
Best regards, 
A

Answer (score 0):

Alex,  What you are asking for is dependent upon a lot of different things. If the software is compiled (which a lot of desktop software is) in some way, you will not likely be able to find this.  Even if it's not, you still might not be able to find this.

You will have to work with a qualified software professional to find this out, and you are unlikely to get that for free on this forum.